# how to save the state of radio buttons in htmlunit

Tags: html, htmlunit

I am using htmlunit to select radio button, and after clicking this button i checked if it is selected and got true which is fine.

my problem is when I leave the page and then back to it the radio button is not checkd and the default one will be the checked one !

does any one has idea about this issue ?

Comment: HtmlUnit is a browser. If the checkbox is not selected, it's because the HTTP server generating the page doesn't select it.

Comment: It is a radio button, but after clicking it I checked if it is selected and got true, which means it is selected but the issue it does not save state, I am not sure if this is because of dynamic issue,

Comment: Why should it save the state? That's entirely dependant on how the web site you're browsing with HtmlUnit works. Most of the time, form elements are not saved until you submit the form containing them. When you go to google.com, enter a word in a search box, then leave the page and reopen it, does the search box contain the word you previously entered? No, it doesn't.

Comment: in your case you are right but when you do the same steps manually, it will still be selected ,

Comment: To be able to answer, we would need to know the exact steps you're doing manually, and to see the code which is supposed to execute these steps. Without this information, we can't help.

Comment: man the idea is not an error in the code because the onclick event is working correctly which means the radio button is checked, but my question if this is a cause of the dynamic issue of htmlunit

Comment: You're asking us to guess, without knowing anything about your code, why you're observing a certain behavior. We're not wizards. We need the code to be able to explain why it works the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody needs solution to this, you need to save the state to HtmlPage. When you want to resume to earlier radio button selection state, can achieve that using following code

```
HtmlPage selectionsHtmlPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
```

in future, at any point when you want to start over from the selection again,

```
webClient.getCurrentWindow().setEnclosedPage(selectionsHtmlPage);
```

This method is just a way to do that operation only when doing this does not affect/break the ideal expected workflow of the web application.